# ios 7 - AVAudioRecorder or AudioToolbox for Record and Play - Not as file - as buffer

Tags: ios, audio, buffer, record

Untill ios6, i used to have audiotoolbox to have record and play (simultaneously) audio using buffers.

I think, 'AVAudioRecorder' does recording into a 'file', not in a 'buffer'.

in current ios 7, since 'audiotoolbox' is deprecated, i'm forced to use 'AVAudioRecorder'.

But the issue is, how to replace the 'file' output to 'buffer' output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use audio queue to record, I have written a [recorder](https://github.com/kudocc/CCKit/blob/master/CCKit/audio/AudioQueueRecorder.m), this is the [demo](https://github.com/kudocc/CCKit/blob/master/CCKitDemo/audio/AudioRecordAudioQueueToFileViewController.m), you can have a try.

Though I write the data to file, but you can copy it into the buffer as you please.